# Mixed-Integer Nearest Optimal Solution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, approximation, mixed-integer-programming

Is it possible to find the nearest solution to optimal for a mixed-integer problem? For example I would want the simplified problem below:

```
f = [1;1;1];
intcon = 1:3;

Aeq = [0.99,0.97,0.15];
beq = 0.16;
lb = zeros(3,1);
ub = [1;1;1]; 

x = intlinprog(f,intcon,[],[],Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

to return `x=[0;0;1]` as this is the nearest integer solution to the objective value of `0.16`. Instead currently it returns

> Intlinprog stopped because no point satisfies the constraints.

Does not necessarily have to run `intlinprog`. Would ideally need to also work if `beq` is low, for example `0.14`.

Comment: Don't post Ax=b as constraint, but minimize the objective norm(Ax-b) / e.g. least-squares. Depending on your norm, this might be a mixed-integer linear-program or something else (qp, socp, ...).

Comment: Thanks. That would also be an option. Do you have an example of applying MI to LS?

Comment: Not for matlab (as i'm not a matlab-user). intlinprog does not seem to be a good candidate here (as the objective, depending on your norm, might be nonlinear which is not supported, but [this example](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/mixed-integer-quadratic-programming-portfolio-optimization.html) talks about linearization approaches. MIQP is not as popular as MI and there are not that much solvers (especially open-source), but every commercial solver will do (gurobi, cplex and co.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can introduce some slack variables to allow some constraint violation when needed as follows:

```
largeValue = 100; % choose some large value to penalise the constraint violation
f_ = [f; largeValue; largeValue]; % penalise both slack variables
Aeq_ = [Aeq, 1, -1]; % add a positive and negative slack variable to the constraint
beq_ = beq;
lb_ = [lb; 0; 0]; % limit the constraint to a positive number
ub_ = [ub; inf; inf];

x_ = intlinprog(f_,intcon,[],[],Aeq_,beq_,lb_,ub_); % solve the adapted problem
x = x_(1:3) % extract the solution of the original problem
```

**Remarks**

- I added two (positive) slack variables, one for a positive constraint violation and another one for a negative constraint violation.
- You should penalise the slack variables with a large value, otherwise it is beneficial to violate your constraints more than strictly necessary. A more general approach would be to determine a good penalisation value based on the values in `f` and `Aeq`, for example

  ```
  largeValue = 2*max(abs(f))/min(abs(Aeq(Aeq ~= 0)))
  ```